# QGraphicsScene won't scale to page when printing

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qprinter

I am writing a program that, among other things, creates a weekly Outlook-esque schedule (days of the week along the top, times down the left side, and boxes in a grid to represent appointments). I've subclassed the QGraphicsScene class and am using it in conjunction with the QGraphicsView to display the schedule in the GUI.

The problem arises now that I am trying to print the schedule. I would like it to print and automatically scale to fit the page. From the research I've done, the code should be relatively simple:

```
QPrinter printer( QPrinter::HighResolution );
if( QPrintDialog( &printer ).exec() == QDialog::Accepted ) 
{
    QPainter painter( &printer );
    schedule_scene->render( &painter );
}
```

However, this produces output with the text labels jammed into the upper-left corner and no visible boxes/gridlines, as if it were trying to render the scene in an unbelievably tiny box. If I make the following change:

`schedule_scene->render( &painter, QRectF( 0, 0, 600, 600 ) );`

then it prints in a small, 600x600 box as expected.

I've been testing this with both the Windows XPS printer and the CutePDF printer, as I don't have an actual printer connected to my development machine right now.

According to the research I've done, QGraphicsScene should scale to fill the page with all default parameters. Why won't my subclassed scene automatically scale to fit the whole page? Did I miss a method I needed to implement?

EDIT: Setting the page size manually in code fixes the problem:

```
QPrinter printer( QPrinter::HighResolution );
if( QPrintDialog( &printer ).exec() == QDialog::Accepted ) 
{
    printer.setPageSize( QPagedPaintDevice::PageSize::Letter );
    QPainter painter( &printer );
    schedule_scene->render( &painter );
}
```

How come the Print dialog does not take care of setting the page size on its own?

Comment: Why are you subclassing the scene? If you merely want to generate a scene filled with some data, you don't need to subclass the scene.

Comment: What are values of `printer.width()` and `printer.height()`?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov The values of printer.width() and printer.height() appear to both be -8, regardless of whether I choose the XPS or CutePDF printer. Is this expected, or possibly an artifact of these virtual printers?

Comment: @KubaOber In the scenes I have graphics (lines, boxes) as well as text that I don't want scaled (itemIgnoresTransformations set to true). When I resize the view widget, some labels need to be repositioned accordingly (to keep them centered, for example). Since the scene doesn't know the dimensions of the view, I subclassed the scene to expose pointers to the text labels, so that the view can "reach in" and reposition them when it is resized. I know that this might not be the best way to handle it (and it's off-topic) but if you think there's a better way I can open another question here on SO.